# summation natural log series addition

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, summation

I have the expression
$$
\frac{\sum_i\ln(x_i)}{p}    
$$

where I have $x_1=20$, $x_2 =30$, $x_3=40$ for the $i$th numbers

I was wondering if I  continue by $[\ln(20+30+40)]/p$ or if I $[\ln20+\ln30+\ln40]/p$

Comment: Use the latter expression.

Comment: The $\ln$ is inside the summation. It's the difference between $\sum_i\ln(x_i)$ and $\ln(\sum_i x_i)$.

Comment: thank you so much, is there any particular reason why? I'm sorry if its a simple question I study biology and really should be more apt at maths! Thank you so much again! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have $\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=1}^3 \ln x_i$ that means $\frac{1}{p}(\ln x_1+\ln x_2 + \ln x_3)$. Had you had $\frac{1}{p}\ln \left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i\right)$ then that would have been equal to $\frac{1}{p}\ln(x_1+x_2+x_3)$.